# Android - Programmatically select menu option

Tags: android

Is there a way to programmatically select a menu option? Basically, I want a button in a view to perform the same action as pressing a specific menu option. I was thinking of trying to call onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) but I don't know what to put for the menu item.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Why don't you have both UI events call a common method?

Comment: The simplest answers are often the best ;) +1

Comment: I have some shared code in onOptionsItemSelected() for all the menu items that I would rather not split up. And I was kind of just hoping there was an easy way to call the menu option.

Comment: @dt0 there's always a way to refactor the code and make it DRY and pretty, especially if it's your own code.  If the shared code is a bunch of runtime variables, maybe you could use a structure that will contain all of it in one place.  If it's functional stuff, maybe you can factor it out into utility methods.  There's always a way, and I'd strongly consider not calling one UI event from another.  If you think about the expressiveness of your code, the menu wasn't clicked so calling a menu click event is a little weird.

Comment: Alright thanks Rich, I went with your suggestion. I realized I didn't have to split anything up and can just factor out the entire onOptionsItemsSelected() method.

Comment: In my case it does not work because I'm using ShareActionProvider and I want the same effect of user click. -1

Comment: It would be useful to be able to programmatically select the menu option while testing, to ensure that the selection actually works.

Answer (score 17):

Yes there is a way to select a menu option! And you are right about calling onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) here is the way to get the MenuItem:

1) first thing you need to do is get the reference of the Menu class inside your Activity here:

```
private Menu menu;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
   this.menu = menu;
   return super.onCreateOptionMenu(menu);
}
```

2) So basically, the Menu class contains all your menu items. So once you have this reference, you simulate the menu click like this:

```
onOptionsItemSelected(menu.findItem(R.id.action_id));
```

...where action_id is the id of the menu item you want to select. you can find this id in your menu xml.

Answer (score 2):

I was also looking for this. and while it makes sense to call the method used when an item gets checked, that will not set the menu item as checked in the UI.

So what I ended up doing was:

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

MenuItem menuItem = (MenuItem)navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_menu_item_1);
        menuItem.setChecked(true);
        onNavigationItemSelected(menuItem);
```

The following did not work as desired for me:

> onOptionsItemSelected(menu.findItem(R.id.action_id));

Comment: If you use NavigationView you need to call onNavigationItemSelected(menuItem). Any way onOptionsItemSelected(menu.findItem(R.id.action_id)) will works too if implement it in ' @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)'. But this way is wrong for side navigation.

Comment: +sVd So are you saying this is the wrong way for side navigation or any navigation? is there a specific scenario when this approach is the correct way? I remember trying a few things, including some listed as answers here but I could not get it to work. This was my first android app i was working on so im sure i made many mistakes. This project was a while ago and im not even with that company any longer. I would like a response for future reference. Since this was the only way i got this to work, i'll leave it here. I'll make changes or a note if needed after your reply.

Comment: +Heriberto Lugo  I just am exclaiming that with *NavigationView* we should use designated interface for it - **public static interface NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener** and implement it in activity. That is why using *onOptionsItemSelected* wrong but still possible. That's all! ;)

Comment: +sVd thanks for the clarification.. im very much a novice in android dev.