# Android - Programmatically select a menu option

Tags: android, selection, android-actionmode, actionmode

I know there's already been a question like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13615229/android-programmatically-select-menu-option) but unfortunately there is no actual answer there.

I'm writing a file manager-like application that uses **only** keyboard input (which, as you could guess, is total fun to code in Android). When a user navigates to a file and does a long-click on it, I programmatically create an `ActionMode` and I'd love to have a way to select (to select, not to simulate a click)  its first item because navigating from the last file, all the way to the top can be a real chore.

So, is there a way to do that?

I have used :

```
getActivity().startActionMode(ActionMode.Callback callback)
```

with `callback` being defined beforehand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought I've already posted that.

Seems like there's no way to select an `ActionMode` item, so I swapped an `ActionMode` for a floating `ContextMenu`, and it worked.